# Adding new categories and subcategories - Magento

Tags: php, magento, categories

What I need is to add new categories and subcategories from .csv file. I can create new root category, but I don't know how to make subcategory:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setStoreId(0);

  $rootCategory['name'] = 'Reserved';
  $rootCategory['path'] = "1"; // for root category
  $rootCategory['display_mode'] = "PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE";
  $rootCategory['is_active'] = 1;

  $category->addData($rootCategory);
$parentCategory= $category; // doesn't work, but i want here to get this (root) category id
  try {
    $category->save();
  }
  catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

CSV file will be formatted like this:

```
root_cat_id;subcat_id;subcat_name;subsubcat_id;subsubcat_name;
ex.
1;2;Animal;3;Dog;
```

How can I get id of just added category, and add subcategory related to this category?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a category the child of another category, set the path to the parent categories path before saving it.

```
$childCategory->setPath($parentCategory->getPath())
```

After the child category is saved (and thus has an ID), the ID will be appended to the path attribute automatically after `save()` is called.
Magento will also automatically set the parent_id and level attributes for you.